# Why does google cache sometimes include multiple html requests

Tags: google-search

This URL of the google cache shows 2 html files in it. How is this possible?

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://www.grandcoulee.com/story/2014/08/20/news/two-top-officers-have-70-years-in/4563.html&strip=0&vwsrc=1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about what appears in the Google cache and it is not a programming question.

Comment: I agree, after looking into the problem further I think it is unrelated to googles cache. It is just the delivery agent.